# URL with variables rewrite

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am not very good with .htaccess, and I am trying to rewrite URLs with variables. I tried to follow other topics advice but couldn't get it to work.

I go some urls that are like this:
`/en/22-products/` (the url continue but I don't want to change the rest)

I would like to change them like this: `/en/catalog/22-products/`

Now I got this in my .htaccess:
`RewriteRule ^en/([0-9]+)-products/?$ /en/catalog/$1-products/ [R,L]`

But it won't work. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Do you have more rules in your root .htaccess?

Comment: Yes I got the basic Joomla SEF .htaccess. I put this rewrite before them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not far. We also need to pick up the trailing part of the url. Do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^en/([0-9]+-products)(.*) /en/catalog/$1$2  [L,R]
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you! 
In the meantime i did write a jQuery based on the pageID that reads the language and properly change url, but this solution i think it's far better.